# djano - can not display an uploaded image from mySQL database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I configured everything as it should and yet I can't display the images from my database.

settings.py :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

models.py

```
class Etudiants(models.Model):
    numeroetudiant = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='numeroEtudiant', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    prenom = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    groupe = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=False, upload_to='images/')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'etudiants'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom + " " + self.prenom
```

views.py :

```
def ajoutetudiant(request): 
    submitted = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EtudiantsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("../ajoutetudiant/")
    else: 
        form = EtudiantsForm()
        if 'submitted' in request.GET:
            submitted = True
    
    return render(request, 'ajoutetudiant.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py (of my project) :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('notes.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

.html :

```
<img src="{{etudiant.photo.url}}"/>
```

The pictures are saved in my database as you can see here. But cannot display it. [image: as you can see here]

My field in mySQL database is "blob". If it shouldn't be blob what should i put ?
[image: imagesql]

Comment: You do not store the images in mysql, but in the file system indicated by the upload_to setting.

Comment: what i have to do so, even if i store the images in the file images/, that should at least display the images no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MySQL field for `photo` should be:

```
`photo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
```